# Microstrip via fence intuition

Tags: via

I want to add a VIA fence to improve the signal of the microstrip shown below.
I know that the distance between vias (brown arrow) is lambda/20.

1. What via diameter to use?
2. What the the vertical distance (blue arrow) between the vias?
3. If I will put a field monitor on the via fence how can I see from the electric field that the via fence is working well?

[image]

Comment: If there's no coplanar ground on the same layer as the trace, what is your via fence connecting to what?

Comment: Why are you adding the stitching vias?  Is it to provide isolation from other signals?

Comment: In your drawing the vias connect to nothing because there's no top layer. Is that right? No point in having a fence if the top is open.

Answer (score 2):

In my experience a via fence is used only when there is a coplanar ground also present in the structure. Meaning a ground plane on the same layer as the microstrip track. Then the via fence prevents signal from radiating out into the dielectric layer.

With the coplanar ground present, the "vertical" distance between the vias should be just enough to allow the vias to connect to the coplanar ground (so maybe .4 mm wider than the separation between the coplanar ground regions.

The via diameter is typically "as small as economically possible" to minimize the space taken by the fence structure.

Without a coplanar ground present, the fence doesn't really do anything to contain the fields, so I wouldn't expect any benefit from using it.

Comment: Everyplace I've seen via stitching used the ground planes were on the layers above and below the trace layer - that is a stripline configuration.  So the stitching served to tie those two  ground planes together.

Comment: Hello The photon ,Yes you are absolutly correct there will be a coplanar arounf the trace,could you please say what distance to take in the vertical side in terms of wavelength?

Comment: @lub2354, "just enough to allow the vias to connect to the coplanar ground" as I said in my answer.

Comment: @SteveSh, it's also used in coplanar waveguide. The value in microstrip is probably not as great because microstrip is lossy regardless.

Comment: @ The Photon - My point is that you do not have to have a ground trace/pour/plane on the same layer as the trace.

Comment: @SteveSh, OK, fair point. But OP's model image shows only one ground plane, so it's unclear what's the point of fencing vias in their situation.

Comment: @The Photon - I agree.  Fencing/stitching without ground planes on the layers above and below the signal layer serves no purpose.